# Convert NFC Scanning result to card account number

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

Using NFC scanning in an android device. I can scan this card with a result bytes of `[4, -109, 62, 122, -84, 105, -128]`. Then I used these 3 methods to get different values

```
private fun getHex(bytes : ByteArray) : String {
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    for (i in bytes.indices.reversed()) {
        val b : Int = bytes[i].and(0xff.toByte()).toInt()
        if (b < 0x10) sb.append('0')
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b))
        if (i > 0)
            sb.append(" ")
    }
    return sb.toString()
}
```

> result => 0ffffff80 69 0ffffffac 7a 3e 0ffffff93 04

```
private fun getDec(bytes : ByteArray) : Long {
    var result : Long = 0
    var factor : Long = 1
    for (i in bytes.indices) {
        val value : Long = bytes[i].and(0xffL.toByte()).toLong()
        result += value * factor
        factor *= 256L
    }
    return result
}
```

> result => -35913707024444668

```
private fun getReversed(bytes : ByteArray) : Long {
    var result : Long = 0
    var factor : Long = 1
    for (i in bytes.indices.reversed()) {
        val value = bytes[i].and(0xffL.toByte()).toLong()
        result += value * factor
        factor *= 256L
    }
    return result
}
```

> result => 1006321468729472

I was told that you get the 16 digit account number as soon as you scan the card. The only time I get the 16 digit values is when I use the getReversed() method. The problem is, on the "Beep" card, the 16 digit number is `6378050082944444`. Do you have any idea on how to get this right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get card ID number using UID from NFC card reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66796028/get-card-id-number-using-uid-from-nfc-card-reader)